# undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersController:0x007fda4c2c5208>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Im getting this error after I submit the form.

undefined method `user_url' for #

I am not using the `resources :users` in my route file and i guess thats why i get the error.

My `routes.rb`

```
TaskManager::Application.routes.draw do
    get "welcome/index"
    root 'welcome#index'

    get 'users/new' => 'users#new'
    post 'users/' => 'users#create'
    post 'users/:first_name' => 'users#show'
end
```

and my `users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController    
def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  @user.save

  if @user.save
    redirect_to @user
  else

  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:first_name])
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email)
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have a `post` for `users#show` instead of a `get`?

Comment: Just use RESTful resources and stop fighting the framework.

Comment: If you want only three routes, you could do `resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :show]`

Answer (score 3):

From your code, I'm guessing that the route you want is the `post 'users/' => 'users#create'`. To Achieve that, I'll you should need to do is change that line to `post 'users/' => 'users#create', :as => 'user'`.

For future reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html